# Call to private method App\Helper\ProfilePrivacy::get_by_contact() from context 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

**Facade code:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ProfilePrivacy extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'profileprivacy';
    }
}

?>
```

**helper code**

```
<?php
namespace App\Helper;
// Server file
use App\Http\Models\Privacy as PrivacyModel;

class ProfilePrivacy
{
    private $_model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_model = new PrivacyModel();
    }
    private function get_by_id($id)
    {

        $result=$this->_model->get_by_id($id);

    }
    private function get_by_contact($id)
    {
        $result=$this->_model->get_by_contact($id);
    }
    private function user_profileimage_privacy($id)
    {
        $result=$this->_model->user_profileimage_privacy($id);

    }


}
?>
```

**Provider**

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Helper\ProfilePrivacy;

use Queue;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;



class ProfilePrivacyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Queue::failing(function ($event) {
        });
    }


    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('profileprivacy', function () {
            return new ProfilePrivacy;
        });
    }
}
```

**app.php**

```
$app->register(App\Providers\ProfilePrivacyServiceProvider::class);
```

**WebRoute**

```
$app->get('democlass', function(){
    $imagepath = \App\Facades\ProfilePrivacy::get_by_contact('test');
    print_r($imagepath);
});
```

i got the error Fatal error: Call to private method App\Helper\ProfilePrivacy::get_by_contact() from context 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\voip_api\api\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221
Where i am doing mistake please overview the code

Comment: get_by_contact($id) is private in your ProfilePrivacy helper. Just make it public?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Class extends problem "Call to private method ... from context ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007020/php-class-extends-problem-call-to-private-method-from-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from private to public function instead

Comment: Why not use protected instead of public?